# filtrar dados de uma consulta em minuscula e sem espaços

Tags: php, html, mysql, banco-de-dados

Como fazer uma consulta ao banco de dados que ignore os acentos e os demais caracteres especiais?

Tenho a tabela produtos que tem o campo nome com os seguintes valores:

"*calçados", "Tênis", "Karaokê e Videokê", etc...*

No `BD` os nomes dos produtos estão com acento e separados por espaço.

Minha URL: `http://meusite.com.br/produtos/calcados`

A página produtos recebe o valor "calcado" e verifico se há produtos com esse nome.

O problema é que, pelo fato de que no banco o nome do produto está gravado com acentos e espaços, quando envio "calcados" não encontro nada, pois só tenho gravado "*calçados*".

Também gostaria que ele considerasse palavras compostas, como:

*Karaokê e Videokê, Karaokê, Videokê...*

**Consulta SQL**

```
 $con = $pdo->query("SELECT * FROM ws_cat_sub WHERE sub_categoria = 'calcados' ");
  $return_id = $con->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
```

Comment: Qual é o gerenciador de banco de dados?

Comment: eu uso o MySql.

Comment: Avalie o uso de COLLATE na cláusula WHERE para resolver a questão de acentuação // Para pesquisa em palavras compostas, avalie o uso do operador LIKE. Neste caso, provavelmente ocorrerá degradação na performance.

Comment: Acho que a melhor forma seria pega todas as categorias em em array e passa o str_replace aí depois fazer a consulta ai sim elimino os espaços

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Não sei se entendi direito, mas acho que você quer efetuar uma busca no banco de dados, mas quer que a pessoa possa buscar sem as acentuações? Se for o caso o problema é que você não deve colocar um sinal de **=** para os resultados, e sim o parametro **LIKE**, então o seu código ficará assim:

```
 $con = $pdo->query("SELECT * FROM ws_cat_sub WHERE sub_categoria LIKE '%calcado%' ");
 $return_id = $con->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
```

**Explicações:** 
**%** = O simbolo de porcentagem indica que pode ter algum caractere antes ou não, isso quer dizer que se a pessoa buscar '**alcado**' *sem o C* irá retornar o **calçado**, pois ela buscou uma palavra que se parece com uma que tem salva no banco de dados, isso se aplica para buscas também como **calcad, alcado** mas não para **aclcado**

**LIKE** = O like é um substituto do **=**. Se você não colocar o **LIKE** vai dar erro! Abaixo estão as referências!

**NOTA:** Caso apareça esse símbolo: � basta utilizar a função `utf8_encode` ou `utf8_decode`.

**REFERÊNCIAS:**

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-comparison-functions.html
http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.utf8-encode.php

BOA SORTE, ESPERO TER AJUDADO!